# Local Branches Not On Remote Branch

Tags: git, branch, local, remote-branch

I have a project that needs to diverge into 3 different branches. Those branches will never be merged anymore (though certain fixes might have to be applied to all 3 branches). In the image below "master" is one of the branches. "Branch1" and "Branch2" were supposed to be separate branches showing a tree ("Graph" on the left column indicates there is no tree). From googling I understand green means local branch only. So how can I push this local branch to the remote and then check out that branch for making modifications (and pushing modifications to that branch).

**Edit:**

After "git push origin master" I now see origin/master. My next steps were:
git branch branch3. Now I had at the bottom green(branch3)/red(master)/beige(origin/master), above branch1 green/beige and above branch2 green/beige.

git checkout branch3
Now the red box was on branch3 and master became green

I made a change to the project and then
git add [changedFile]
git commit -m "..."
git push --set-upstream origin branch3

Now I had what I really was looking for which is:

[image]

Comment: Can you please provide some more details? What program is the screenshot from? What OS do you use? What are you using for your git hosting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Branch1` and `Branch2` already have their remotes (`origin/`). Only your `master` doesn't (which is confusing). Anyway, you can push any local branch to remote (`origin` in your case) with this command:

`git push origin master`

Optionally, you can add `-u` to tell git to track this branch:

`git push -u origin master`

You can also use git in a terminal to see your repo graph:

`git log --oneline --decorate --graph`

Comment: amaslenn, thanks for the response. I updated my question based on your response. I tried to upvote you but they don't let me because I am still rather new here. I still appreciate your help.

Comment: @HuF. you are welcome! (you should still be able to mark it as the answer if it is really what you were looking for)